# setDate() returns number 1603240915215 instead of a date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const date = new Date('August 19, 2020 23:15:30');
const event = new Date();
  console.log(`event.setDate(date.getDate() + 1));
```

this code is supposed to return a date but its not returnign a date instead it is returning a number 1603240915215

can some one help me to get the date instead of such number?

Comment: "supposed to return a date but its not returnign a date instead it is returning a number". That's not what the docs say https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const dateObj = new Date(1603240915215);
```

Answer (score 4):

`.setDate` return milliseconds. You want to access the dateInstance instead:

```js
const day = new Date('August 19, 2020 23:15:30'), nextDay = new Date();
nextDay.setDate(day.getDate()+1); console.log(nextDay.toString());
```